# Redirect to your custom page after login- Django

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin

Whenever I login from the **Django admin site**, It redirects me to the Admin Site of the django. Whereas, I want to redirect to my ***own custom page***. How It's done? Thanks

(It redirects me to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ after a successful login. Whereas i want to go to the main page like, http://127.0.0.1:8000.)

Comment: Well, the solution for this is that you've to make your own login page, and in the views.py create your own function, and redirect it to whereever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this line in your `settings.py` file:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/some/url'
```

And also you must define your this `url` in `urls.py` and create `veiw` in your `views.py` for that url.

Comment: It's not working. It redirects me to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ after a successful login. Whereas i want to go to the main page like, http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: You should rewrite your own login page. When you request to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` and your are not login, you redirect to login page and after login you will send to `/admin` page. @ShehrozAyaz

Answer (score 0):

If you have `?next=` parameter set is not enough to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in you setting.py. You need to also handel this parameter. As say docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url):

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
> Default: '/accounts/profile/'
>
> The URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected after login
> **when the LoginView doesn’t get a next GET parameter.**

In my case I just set `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = ""` instead of `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = "next"` in my `django.contrib.auth` and it works fine.